# Pyramid Lucas-Kanade algorithm with Java

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing

I have a question about Lucas-Kanade optical-flow algorithm.
I understood that "Pyramid" Lucas-Kanade algorithm is more better than simple Lucas-Kanade algorithm. So I made its program with Java because I can't use OpenCV's program. 
But the program doesn't work well. So please teach me the program of "Pyramid" Lucas-Kanade 
algorithm, or the Web-site that the program of "Pyramid" Lucas-Kanade algorithm is shown.

I am a Japanese student, so I'm not good at English. I'm sorry. But please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Lucas-Kanade algorithm with Image Pyramids which is available in OpenCV. It is one of the fastest algorithms to calculate Optical Flow.

Use OpenCV's implementation of Lucas-Kanade algorithm with Image Pyramids, Forget Java if you are trying to do Image Processing. Many have tried to use Java and failed in between because of performance issues required for Image Processing, even though I literally make a living out of Java I don't recommend it for Image Processing. Learn C++ if you have to and do it using OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you for replying to me soon. I　understand. I will try to learn OpenCV. Thank you!